# Syntax error when defining 2 functions in python

Tags: python

I've *very* new to programming so sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm trying to make a program with multiple functions, but whenever I attempt to define one it comes up with an error.

```
def startUp():
    promptName()

def promptName():
    name = input("Hello. Please enter your name: ")

startUp()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If it helps the def part in def promptName(): is highlighted red.

Comment: `def` means "define." So before you define what a function `promptName` is, your program has no idea what to do with the string, "promptName()".

Comment: @Christian I guess it should compile just fine. Are you using the IDLE?

Comment: @AndrewCheong: No. What you said matters only when actually running the function -- not while defining it. Also, this is a `SyntaxError`. OP probably needs to show the entire file. (EDIT: Not entire file, file with MVCE)

Comment: The "Syntax Error" message should have told you *where* the error is, at which line. Please include the *complete* error output, in full and unedited. Also make sure you copy-pasted the *actual* code and didn't rewrite it in the question (thereby possibly fixing errors in your actual code).

Comment: That is the entire file. And yes I am using IDLE.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Christian: Probably your setup/environment/editor specific problem. [It works just fine on ideone.](http://ideone.com/J3YS4v)

Comment: @AndrewL the newest one, 3.5.2

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above code as it is written. You should check to make sure everything is spelled and indented correctly and that you are using colons as necessary.

Comment: Like everybody are saying, [your program (***as you show it***) is fine](http://ideone.com/fZ27nB). The error is with something you *don't* show us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd bet you're trying to paste the entire thing into a Python interpreter session. The command line interpreter needs things entered one block at a time, so try pasting the `startUp` function, hit enter, then `promptName` and enter, and then run the whole thing with the last line.

Alternatively, save it all as a .py file and run the file.

Comment: If I run it as a .py it just opens and closes very quickly, but it works if I enter it into the interpreter separately?

Comment: If you use the IDLE, make a new file within it. Then type in your code and run it with f5

Comment: I mean an actual file, not just the shell. In that case a syntax error should not pop up.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I get a box popup just saying called Syntax Error which just says invalid syntax.

Comment: Should I just reinstall python?

Comment: Best is probably if you post a screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: I downloaded the Python installer and repaired it and it seems to be working now, was Python corrupt or something?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted here is absolutely fine (regarding the syntax). Please check whether you have forgotton a colon or so in you original code.

Regarding the code:
If you define a variable (like name within promptName()) within a function, you cannot access that variable from outside the function. To make use of it, you have to return it or state it explicitly as global variable.

Comment: I've stripped it down to what I put in the description so that is the entire file and it still won't work. Should I reinstall Python?

Comment: @RafaelAlbert Should this not be a comment?

Comment: It's the best answer he can give at this time, with some suggestions that might work.

Comment: I believe so, I've triple checked it online and it checks out.